# How to add a symbol or letter in front of only bold cells on microsoft excel 2013?

Tags: excel

I have been trying to figure out how to add only this symbol (~) in front of text that is bold
in excel

Comment: Inversely, you could use conditional formatting to render the cells starting with a ~ as bold

Answer (score 0):

A simple VBA solution that will modify all emboldened cells in the users' Selection of cells.  You could put this into a user-defined function perhaps?

```
Sub selBold()
Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In Selection
        If cl.Font.Bold Then cl = "~" & cl
    Next
End Sub
```